# How to remove background from an image (subtraction)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following things:

- Image before an item is in place (just the background), like this:

[image: Background image]

- Image with the item, like this:

[image: Image with item]

In this case, I want to have an image with just the lens cap. How can I substract these two images? I think OpenCV would fit good for this problem, but I have an issue with substracting these images.

I have found something similarly in this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html But, they are just talking about using in video and not with before/after image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL remove background image from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531932/pil-remove-background-image-from-image)

Comment: You can only subtract if the background is exactly the same, you don't even need a lot of opencv for that, you are basically comparing every pixel and removing the ones, that are the same or withing a threshold.

Comment: @user1767754 The purpose of (advanced) background subtractors as described in the linked tutorial exactly is to perform even when the background is slightly changing, for example in videos. The method described by you most likely only works for artificially inserted objects in some background image. Even the difference between the two example images given in the question is "huge". (I guess, these are two different photos taken.) So, it's totally valid to use a background subtractor here.

Answer (score 1):

The linked tutorial (almost) does the job! You have a "video" of two frames, so just feed these two frames to the said background subtractor, and see what happens:

```py
import cv2
from skimage import io  # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read images from web
img_bg = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMoqy.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyrKo.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Set up and feed background subtractor (cf. tutorial linked in question)
backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
_ = backSub.apply(img_bg)
mask = backSub.apply(img)

# Morphological opening and closing to improve mask
mask_morph = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (21, 21)))
mask_morph = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (21, 21)))

# Generate output
output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, None, mask_morph)

# Visualization
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('mask_morph', mask_morph)
cv2.imshow('output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The generated `mask` from the background subtractor looks like this:

[image: Mask]

So, we need some morphological opening and closing to improve the mask, see [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f). Then, the modified `mask_morph` looks like this:

[image: Modified mask]

Using [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) with the mask, we get the desired `output`:

[image: Output]

Please notice, the wider edge mostly below the cap, comes from the shadow, as also mentioned in the tutorial.

Hope that helps!